# Does measuring the operator of a wave function collapse the wave function to the measured eigenstate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction-collapse

Suppose you have a state described by the wave function $\psi(x) = \phi_1(x)+2\phi_2(x)+3\phi_3(x)$ , where the $\phi$s are normalised eigenfunctions of a Hermitian operator $\hat{O}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 5, \lambda_3 = 9$.

**What happens to the wave function if you measure $\hat{O}$ and you obtain the result $\lambda_2=5$?**

My answer is that the wave function immediately collapses to $\psi(x) = 5\phi_2$

***EDIT**: My answer should be $\psi(x) = 10\phi_2$,  I think*

Is that correct? Or should I state the probability with which the wave function will collapse to that state:

$<\hat{O}> = \sum|c_n|^2\lambda_n$   where $|c_n|^2$ is the probability of the $n^{th}$ state.

Comment: If the $\phi$ are normalized, then your $\psi$ is not normalized, making this question difficult to understand.

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub The normalised wave function is $\psi(x) = \sqrt{1/14}(\phi_1(x)+2\phi_2(x)+3\phi_3(x))$

Comment: Your final wave function, whatever it is, should be normalized. This will tell you what coefficient to put out in front (if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well wavefunctions are technically rays, so what you wrote is acceptable, although usually one would normalize the wavefunction again. Once you have measured $\hat O$ and obtained $5$, you are past the point of asking about probabilities. Before measurement you have probabilities but it's like rolling dice. Once the dice is rolled and you got $6$, you don't ask what the probability is of having a $4$ because it is clearly zero.

Put another way, probability in quantum mechanics means that if you have $n$ identically prepared systems, and you perform the measurement on each one of them, then the fraction of times you get a result $x$ is given by some probability function $p(x)$ as $n\to \infty$. If you only perform the measurement once, or have already performed the measurement, then the probability is simply not defined.

Btw, all this wavefunction collapse business is just an [idealization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children), because all our experiments point to the fact that everything is ruled by quantum mechanics, and unitarity is a central tenet of quantum mechanics. Wave function collapse is not a unitary process, [decoherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoherence) and [einselection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einselection) is. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a little confusion here: the thing you wrote in the last line is the expectation value of a measurement on the state $\psi$: $\langle\psi|\hat O|\psi\rangle \equiv \langle \hat O \rangle$. However, the expectation value of finding your system in the state $|\phi_n\rangle$ after a measurement $\hat O$ is $\langle\phi_m|\hat O|\psi\rangle$, but I get a different result from yours:
\begin{align}
\langle\phi_m|\hat O|\psi\rangle &= \langle\phi_m|\sum_n |\phi_n\rangle\lambda_n \langle\phi_n|\sum_i c_i |\phi_i\rangle\\
 &= \sum_n\sum_i c_i\lambda_n\langle\phi_m|\phi_n\rangle\langle\phi_n|\phi_i\rangle \\
&= \sum_n\sum_i c_i\lambda_n\delta_{mn}\delta_{in}\\
&= c_m\lambda_m
\end{align}

Thus, the expectation value of finding your system in eigenstate 2 is 5*2 = 10.

Comment: "the expectation value of finding your system in eigenstate 2" I'm not sure that's really a thing.